# Three buttons has the same text 'select'. Is there any way I can locate each button?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I have three buttons which have the text 'select'.

Can I write the code to interact with these select buttons? They don't have any ids or name.

I am placing two of my buttons here:

```
<button class="btn btn-default ng-scope" type="button" data-ng-click="onBtnSelectClicked(coverage)" translate="l_choose">Select</button>

<button class="btn btn-default ng-scope" type="button" data-ng-click="onBtnSelectClicked(coverage)" translate="l_choose">Select</button>
```

If you tell me some other way to interact this button that's fine too.

EDIT

I have found an answer to this question, here is the answer

b.buttons(:text,'Select')[1].click

Comment: How do you as a human determine which `select` you want to interact with? For example, presumably you use the surrounding text or visual layout to know. You can use the same approach to tell Watir which one to use.

Comment: I was using this b.buttons[0].click but many buttons are there, So I was asking Is there anyother way to locate these select buttons alone? So I could pass the index for this select buttons.

Comment: What @JustinKo was asking is if you're an end user of the site, how do you decide which button you want to click? I'm guessing more of the html and a specific example of which you want to click and why would lead to the best quality answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see what you've tried writing toward solving this problem. SO isn't a "give me code" site, it's to help correct problems with the code you've written. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: What do you mean "interact"? To parse and extract information about the HTML, or to dynamically change the HTML in the browser? If you want to parse and extract information look at Nokogiri. There are many examples of its use on SO and on the internet.

Comment: Tin Man, I am not asking the code, read my question carefully please, I was sorting out Is there anyway to to locate that button.

Comment: Tin Man, Please Read the Below answer of Makjb lh, he has explained for you.

Comment: Justin Ko, I have found an answer now, here is the answer 'b.buttons(:text,'Select')[0].click', this click the first button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beg to differ from above Comments. When in UI testing we Very routinely come upon such scnearios for rich applications. [Angular/Dojo etc]

It is also possible they put intentionally vague properties so that the user can dynamically re arrange and or increase decrease frames/panels as he needs. I've had huge arguements with dev guys on this part - evn now it does not make much sense to me how much ever they explain.

Consider this - you may want to open up some kind of doc and compare side by side and you have same elements in two frames - so lets say opnen a frame and split it into two and say compare / find / select etc etc may be some of the common objects that someone can design.

So I am guessing - if in any case the dev has intentionally decided to go with same properties - **the parent or any ancestor should DEFINITIVELY differ**. So you need to narrow that down and go for it. This IS the right approach since your tests wont break unless intent/functionality is updated specifically.

if not then this is a poor application design, you may possibly let dev know for some text differentiation.

Comment: Yes Thank you Makjb Ih.

Comment: Up voted your answer, By the way I found a new way to click, I would like to tell you, I could access like "b.buttons(:text,'Select')[0].click", and this would click the first select button.

Comment: Wow thats a new for me !!! lemme check then - I guess for every element type there should be element and also elements for Watir. Thanks a lot for points !!

Comment: Yeah it groups under that hash If I write b.buttons(:text=>'Select'), then it returns all the buttons which has select text. buttons,text_fields,checkboxes receives hash as inputs, So my requirement was fulfilled there.